# GCP IoT Core Rejects Public Key with "Certificate is in an invalid PEM format" Error message. What could be wrong?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, iot, google-cloud-iot, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am learning how to work with IoT Core. Upon trying to create a device, I encounter an error with the public key. "Certificate is in an invalid PEM format" it says. This public key was supplied as part of the qwiklabs instructions so I don't know what could be wrong.

Maybe it has to do with the instruction below, but I can't fiqure what the error is.

[image]

This is the lab: [here](https://googlecoursera.qwiklabs.com/focuses/23172)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured the problem. 
It was not anything serious. Upon creating the device, I chose a wrong Public Key Format. RS256 instead of RS256_X509.
Solved the problem by selecting the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for following up with your own answer.